# Get margin of a View

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

How can I get the margin value of a View from an Activity? The View can be of any type.

After a bit of searching I found out ways to get padding of a view, but couldn't find anything on Margin. Can anyone help?

I tried something like this,

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams vlp = view.getLayoutParams();
int marginBottom = ((LinearLayout.LayoutParams) vlp).bottomMargin;
```

This works, but in the above code I have assumed the view to be a `LinearLayout`. But I need to get the `margin` attribute even when I don't know the view type.

Answer (score 188, accepted):

try this:

```
View view = findViewById(...) //or however you need it
LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
```

margins are accessible via

```
lp.leftMargin;
lp.rightMargin;
lp.topMargin;
lp.bottomMargin;
```

**edit:**
perhaps `ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams` will work for you. It's a base class for other `LayoutParams`.

```
ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams lp = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html

Comment: Actually I was expecting something like this, but I don't think there is any direct class called `LayoutParams`. There are classes like `FrameLayout.LayoutParams`, `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`, but nothing like `LayoutParams` in itself. And since I don't know the type of the view, I cannot use any of the former classes.

Comment: what about `ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams lp = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();` then?

Comment: Should be ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams lp = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();

Answer (score 36):

Try

```
ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams vlp = (MarginLayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams()

vlp.rightMargin
vlp.bottomMargin
vlp.leftMargin
vlp.topMargin
```

This returned the correct margains for my view atleast.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html

Answer (score 5):

now use this edited code. this will help you

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp=(FrameLayout.LayoutParams)mainLayout.getLayoutParams();

lp.leftMargin  // for left margin
lp.rightMargin   // for right margin
```

Comment: The methods you mentioned give the left, right, top and bottom positions of the view, I need the margins.

Comment: Not necessarily. A view maybe placed in a `LinearLayout` with `horizontal` orientation. If its the second view in the layout the `view.getLeft()` method would give me the the coordinate of its left but the left margin of the view from its adjacent view.

Comment: What if the View is a `LinearLayout`?

Answer (score 3):

As others suggested, layout_margin# is the space between the parent's # edge and your view.

- # replaces "Left", "Right", "Top" or "Bottom"

Getting/setting margins worked for me with:

```
ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) mView.getLayoutParams();
params.topMargin += 20;
mView.requestLayout();
```

Of course, my View was indeed a ViewGroup and the parent was a ViewGroup as well. In most cases, you should cast your layout params to the parent's View class LayoutParams (in this case it's ViewGroup and RelativeLayout)