# How to get the margin of layout in android?

Tags: android

How to get the distance between the top of child layout and Main Screen in Android?

I set up the Relative layout at somewhere of Main Screen. Now, I wanna know that the top and left margin of layout.

Comment: You'll have to use the LayoutParams to get the margins Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7468011/2310673)

Comment: I can`t collect lp.leftmargin and lp.topMargin.I think I had used Relative Layout. Thank you ... @bakriOnFire